# Iterating Through ComboBox And Referencing Items Using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some custom made controls:

1) 1 for string inputs (textbox)

2) 1 for multiple string inputs (combobox)

3) 1 for integer inputs

Page 1 does some processing and depending on user input, any number of the controls are added to page 2 in any order. Due to the fact that the addition of the controls above, along with their ordering is completely dynamic, I have had to refer to the custom controls quite generally using refelection:

For example, if I want to reference a property (e.g. 'Value') within one of the controls above I use the following

```
c.GetType().GetProperty("Value")
```

My problem is the following:

I need to access the **items** in the control containing the combo box. Usually I would do something like:

```
foreach(string item in ComboBox1.items){}
```

This seems slightly tricky when referencing the control via reflection....Any ideas?

Note: I want to keep using reflection if possible....

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the `Items` property of the object so use the `GetProperty` reflection method.  [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/) is a good example of getting the property information dynamically, and then [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/11/19/97548.aspx) is an example to set the value.

Comment: I can't use the get property method. c.GetType().GetProperty("ComboBox1").GetProperty("Items") is not legal

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
foreach (var cntrl in Page2.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
     //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a the property you could do the following not sure if this is something you 
are looking to try.

```
PropertyInfo prop  = controlType.GetProperty(propertyName);// Gets Items
MethodInfo methInfo = prop.PropertyType.GetMethod(methodName); // gets the method ('Items.Add')
object obj      = prop.GetValue(newControl, null);         // gets the current 'Items
methInfo.Invoke(prop.GetValue(newControl, null), new object[] { newValue });
```